# How to attach a view to bottom sheet in compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

I need to attach a divider and textview to top of persistent bottom sheet. So that it will look like a part of bottomsheet.[image]

And on clicking divider bottom sheet should collapse and expand.

````
sheetContent = {
          Column(){
                  Divider(
                      modifier = Modifier
                          .clickable {// if i write logic to expand and collapse bottomsheet here, it wont work
                          }
                  )
                  Text()
                  Box(){
                      //display list of users
                  }
              }```
````

Comment: and what is the issue?

Comment: if i write this whole code inside sheet content, then click function is not working . Even i click on divider also ,it wont expand or collapse bottomsheet. I need that to happen. ```BottomSheetScaffold(){Button(onClick = {//adding logic here works} )}``` - only this works.

Comment: It should work. Add the complete reproducible code.